# If X is N(0,1) RV find the pdf $X^{-2}$

Tags: probability

If X is N(0,1) RV find the pdf $X^{-2}$

So $X=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/\lambda}$

So $P(Y\le y)=P(X^{-2}\le y)= 1-P(X \ge \sqrt y)=1-\int_0^\sqrt y \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/\lambda} dx$

I don't know how to get the integral of this. I put it into an integral calculator and it came out as some really messed up number, but I was planing to get the derivative of that in terms of y

Comment: If $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then its probability density function is $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}\qquad \text{not}\qquad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/\lambda}$$There are no $\lambda$ parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(Y\leq y)=P(|X| \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt y})=2\int_{1/\sqrt y }^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-x^{2}/2}dx=2[1-\Phi(1/\sqrt y)]$ where $\Phi$ is the standard normal distribution function.

Comment: don't you need to do $1-P(|X|\ge \frac1{\sqrt y})$? Because you flipped the equality?

Comment: o nvm you integrate from $1/\sqrt y$ to $\infty$

Comment: $Y\leq y$ is exactly $X^{2} \geq \frac 1 y$ or $|X| \geq \frac 1 {\sqrt y}$. I am not taking complements. @user8714896

Comment: How come you can get rid of $\lambda$?

Comment: @user8714896 Sorry, there was a typo.

Comment: Should there be a $\lambda$ in your final solution?

Comment: @user8714896 It is given that $X$ is $N(0,1)$. There is no $\lambda$ in $N(0,1)$. What I have typed is correct.